# Nuxt + Vuetify can't change default dark theme's background

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I want to overwrite dark theme's default color (in nuxt.config.js | Nuxt + Vuetify), but I can't. When I changed light theme's default theme it changes. Who faced like problem.

```
themes: {
    dark: {
      primary: colors.blue.darken2,
      accent: colors.grey.darken3,
      secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
      info: colors.teal.lighten1,
      warning: colors.amber.base,
      error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
      success: colors.green.accent3,
      background: '#13171c'
    },
  },
```

Thanks for answer...

Answer (score 1):

you need to add **dark: true**

```
vuetify: {
        theme: {
          dark: true,
          themes: {
            dark: {
              primary: colors.blue.darken2,
              accent: colors.grey.darken3,
              secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
              info: colors.teal.lighten1,
              warning: colors.amber.base,
              error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
              success: colors.green.accent3,
              background: "#13171c",
            },
          },
        },
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I had dark: true,

Answer (score 0):

go to the plugin folder

call it vuetify.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default (ctx) => {
const vuetify = new Vuetify({
theme: {
   dark: false // From 2.0 You have to select the theme dark or light here
   }
 })

 ctx.app.vuetify = vuetify
 ctx.$vuetify = vuetify.framework
}
```

and make sure to add it to the nuxt.config plugins

```
  plugins: [
  '@/plugins/vuetify'
  ],
```